# How to pass text/variable from php script to input value?

Tags: php, html

**I need to get id and name from URL when I click edit anchor and I get it actually but I can't post data to input value to make an update by the text input ...**
here is my HTML form :

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Category Name</label>
   <input id="cc-pament" name="category-name" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
   <button id="payment-button" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Save
   </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

here is HTML TABLE And have the Edit anchor to go if isset

```
<thead>
 <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Edit</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody action="" method="get">
    <?php 
      $query = " select * from category ";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
      while($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$cat['cat_id']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$cat['cat_name']}</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='?edit={$cat['cat_id']}&category_name={$cat['cat_name']}'  name='edit' 
              class='btn 
        btn-info'> Edit</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='delete_category.php?id={$cat['cat_id']}' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a> 
        </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

here is the PHP code

```
 if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    # code...
    $name= $_GET['category_name'];
    echo $_POST['category-name']= $name;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "name of url"?
here is some info about the url https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php
Also explode() is really useful

Comment: I mean I use $_GET['id'] to get information of category_id and category_name from the link after I click on edit anchor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, I believe you want to populate the category-name field on your form based the edit value in the URL.

If so, you have most of what you need, you simply need to insert it into the HTML(I am assuming the form is part of a PHP script as well).

```php
   <input id="cc-pament" name="category-name" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= htmlentities($_GET["edit"]??"") ?>">
```

Be sure to encode the value with `htmlentities` or similar to avoid XSS vulnerabilities.

Side note, what exactly is the intent of this line?

```php
    echo $_POST['category-name']= $name;
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your effort.... Now actually here's my problem how to post information that I get it from the link or url box and post it on input value?

Comment: If you want to put it in the form to post, the answer I provided is correct. Are you trying to initiate a POST request from the GET request? I'm not entirely sure I follow.

Comment: I solve it by IF (isset($_GET['edit']){echo $_GET['category_name'] Inside the value input